# Access standard menus via command table with Visual Studio Packages (vsx)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, package, vsx

Is it possible to access default menus from Visual Studio in package development?

For example to disable or hide the **File - New - Project** menu item.

Comment: Why don't you use Visual Studio Isolated Shell to remove standard functionally of Visual Studio?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Carlos.

Yes, it makes sense you should not be able to do that. But I thought I did it years ago using Visual Studio 10, setting only the command table. But I would not trust my own memory on this one. I just got curious how far we have access to the default elements of Visual Studio.